# Which PHP functions use __toString

Tags: php, standards, tostring

Which PHP functions call an objects __toString method when passed an object?

Take the following example:

```
class url {

    protected $url;

    function __construct($url) {
        $this->setUrl($url);
    }

    public function setUrl($url) {
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function getUrl() {
        return $this->url;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->getUrl();
    }

}

$url = new url('http://example.com');
var_dump(in_array($url,array('http://example.com')));
```

The call to in_array evaluates to true when passed the url object.

The following also evaluates to true, but what is it doing internally, is it comparing two objects or two strings?

```
var_dump(in_array($url,array($url)));
```

Would it be better to explicitly say strings should be compared?

```
var_dump(in_array((string)$url,array('http://example.com')));
```

Do all PHP functions similar to in_array see an object as a string if it has a __toString method or is it just some of them?  Therefore would it be better to explicitly say (string) before passing an object?

Examples for testing == comparison.

```
$url = new url('http://example.com');
$url2 = new url('http://example.com');
var_dump(in_array($url,array('http://example.com'))); #1
var_dump(in_array($url,array($url))); #2
var_dump(in_array($url,array($url2))); #3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php):

> When using the comparison operator (==), object variables are compared in a simple manner, namely: Two object instances are equal if they have the same attributes and values, and are instances of the same class.
>
> When using the identity operator (===), object variables are identical if and only if they refer to the same instance of the same class.

So, in answer to your question about `in_array`, it appears that the two objects are compared using the comparison operator (`==`). There is no conversion to string (via `__toString()` or any other way) before comparison.

More generally, I have found this to be the case for *almost* all objects in PHP - the only exceptions are classes that encapsulate system resources, like `PDO` or objects like closures (for reasons that I don't fully understand).

It is not necessary to cast the object(s) to strings before doing the comparison.

Comment: Regarding PDO and closure objects, these are implemented in C and exposed to PHP *as though they were* objects, but don't actually share all the logic of objects defined with a PHP class. I guess you could think of them as not inheriting from the same base as a PHP `class`.

Comment: __toString() conversions must be done based on context then, or otherswise #1 would not return true if __toString() was not called before comparison.
It does appear to use == under the hood because #3 returns true even when the __toString() method is made to return different values using rand().